# Partial home electrical rewire

Tags: electrical

I am a new homeowner. My lady and I have lived here for almost one year now. I've lived through a near-complete home restoration throughout my youth in my parents' home, and have picked up quite a few sets of skills when it comes to all things DIY. I've worked in a hardware store for several years, and have refined said skills there.

So far, I've basically only touched aesthetics in the home - removed all the old floors on the main floor, to set down a new subfloor and hardwood.

We are now planning more major renovations in the home : tearing down two walls upstairs to convert from a two bedroom floor to a master suite. Seeing as I will be doing major work, I wanted to get your input on my electrical situation.

The panel is a new (less than 10 year old) 200A breaker box. The electrician who installed it rewired into the box the original home wiring - non-grounded paper-covered wire. It looks tired and brittle. This also causes me issue when wanting to plug certain appliances that require a 3-pin plug (the original plugs are the old two pin plugs).

I have an unfinished basement where I can follow every single wire from panel to wherever it runs upward.

In your opinion, is it possible to rewire the portions of the house affected by simply removing my connections from the panel, then opening the wall boxes, attaching a wire fish and pulling the old wire and fish through the walls, to be able to pull new wiring back, or could I run into trouble doing so? I know that some areas are tighter and I will need to pull some drywall, but in your experience, could I get lucky enough that this could work on some lines?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check out [wire pull rods](https://www.google.com/search?q=wire+pull+pole&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=wire+pull+rod), fish tapes are too flimsy.

Answer (score 7):

Not likely.  The cabling it almost certainly secured with staples within the walls, ceilings, and floors.  Which will make it impossible to use the existing wiring to fish the new cables.